# How to detect any keyboard or mouse input from background script?

Tags: gnome, bash, 18.04, keyboard, mouse

I left my laptop unattended and unlocked and my colleagues sent a message to the whole service saying, in my name, that I liked them and offered them breakfast the next day.

I want to give my colleagues a bit of a surprise the next time they try that. The idea is to have a background script that once activated would wait for any user input (keyboard or mouse) and then play a very loud sound (and maybe a scary picture).

I've got most of it except detecting keyboard or mouse usage. It's difficult because I'm not prompting text.

I don't need to know what have been typed or done, I just need to know it happened, so the trap catches the "joker".

The final product would be [a script](https://pastebin.com/0JYwUaDj) running from startup and would lock computer automatically based on Bluetooth signal strength. Well, rather than just locking it, it would set a trap that would lock PC after scaring the s**t out of my colleagues.

I've made an [UML diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlB9Y.png) if you need more context.